# Request fail with Laravel API in production

Tags: laravel, rest, deployment

I deployed an API in laravel. The problem that is occurring is the following: the online API always returns me '200 ok', without reaching at least the login controller. With this same API, I ran the test on localhost and it worked. Do I need to set any more permissions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: In my case, I need to know if there is any further need for permission to publish an API in Laravel.

Comment: No there is not, But you can show your log file. That will solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using Passport for API authentication?

Comment: The version I use does not support Passport

Comment: Are you using `auth:api` middleware to protect your api routes?

Answer (score 0):

When another app tries to access a route by the API you created, that app will need to provide a key authorized by your application. This guarantees bots are not misusing your app. This could explain why it works when ran localhost is accepted, but on production, well it fails, due that the external apps accessing your application don't have the client key. Some code would help to better assist you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Comment: The version I use is 5.4. Can I show you how my routes are / api.php

Comment: Please can you check this url to enhance answer quality https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks